I cannot open anaconda navigator in Ubuntu
Can anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?  I installed Anaconda in Ubuntu and ran anaconda-navigator but it doesn't work and shows this error:
Thanks so much for your help.


It looks like you are starting it from a non-graphics terminal. As anaconda-navigator is a graphics program,  you must start it from a terminal running underneath a GUI environment.

Thank you so much @waltinator. I checked and the server that I'm using only allows operation with CUI.
